# Obtener todas las coincidencias solapadas en expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo este string de ejemplo en Javascript, `"246126667"`, y quiero obtener todas las subcadenas que tengan 2 números cualquiera a la izquierda y un 6 al final, es decir, `["246","126","266","666"]`, y para eso le aplico un `match` con la expresión regular `[0-9]{2}6`, y el parámetro `g` para obtener los resultados, pero no funciona como yo quiero.

```js
console.log(
  "246126667".match(/[0-9]{2}6/g)
)
```

El problema es que en vez de devolver los 4 números, solo devuelve `["246","126"]`. ¿Es posible resolver esto mediante expresiones regulares? ¿Hay alguna otra manera?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Problema

La expresión que utilizaste (`[0-9]{2}6`) está muy bien. El tema principal de por qué no coincide con caracteres solapados es porque el motor de expresiones regulares **consume** los caracteres con los que coincide. Por lo tanto, luego de coincidir con `"126"` en

```
246126667
   ^^^
```

la posición para intentar la siguiente coincidencia será:

```
246126|667
      ^
     acá
```

y no encontrará otros 3 dígitos terminados en `6`.

### Solución

Una [inspección positiva](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) (o [*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) intenta una coincidencia pero, si coincide, **vuelve a la posición en la que se encontraba antes de intentarlo**. Es decir, no consume caracteres. La sintaxis es

```
(?=expresión)
```

Entonces, este regex coincidirá con lo que estás buscando

```
/(?=\d{2}6)/g
```

> `\d` es lo mismo que `[0-9]` en JavaScript.

Pero hay un agregado: como no consume caracteres, coincide con la posición, y no con los 3 caracteres que estás queriendo obtener. Para eso, usamos un [grupo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) (lo rodeamos entre paréntesis) para capturar el texto.

Además, es necesario usar [`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) para luego obtener el texto capturado en `match[1]`, y una condición extra para evitar loops infinitos que se deben a un bug conocido de JavaScript.

**Regex**

```
/(?=(\d{2}6))/g
```

**Código**

```js
const texto = "246126667",
      regex = /(?=(\d{2}6))/g;
let   match;

while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) { //evitar loop infinito
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    //imprimir el texto capturado por el grupo 1
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

---

> **¿Por qué es necesario evitar un loop infinito?**
>
> En la solución, agregué una condición para ver si el inicio de la
>   coincidencia (`match.index`) es la misma posición que donde se
>   iniciará el siguiente intento (`regex.lastIndex`). En caso de que sea
>   la misma, se incrementa en 1 la posición.
>
> ```
> if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) { //evitar loop infinito
>     regex.lastIndex++;
> }
> ```
>
> Esto se debe a que, como la coincidencia es en realidad [de largo
>   cero](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html), ya que la aserción no consume caracteres, y el resultado del
>   método realmente es una cadena vacía (`""`), la posición desde donde
>   se intenta el regex no avanza ninguna posición. Por eso, se modifica
>   manualmente para que no siga intentando coincidir desde la misma posición,
>   entrando en un loop infinito.
>
> Esta condición es una buena práctica a utilizar en todos los casos en
>   los que se utilice el modificador [`/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) ([global](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)) y un bucle
>   con [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). Además, no todos los navegadores se
>   comportan igual. Incluso en expresiones que no deberían jamás devolver
>   una cadena vacía, es una buena salvaguarda, y recomiendo utilizar
>   siempre esta construcción.
>
> JavaScript tiene una de las peores implementaciones de expresiones
>   regulares dentro de los lenguajes comúnmente utilizados ([ver más
>   info](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-javascript.html)). Si bien este comportamiento no es un "*bug*" per se
>   ([*<sub><sup>RESOLVED INVALID</sup></sub>*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=252356) en Bugzilla), utilicé
>   el término porque es un concepto erróneo en la implementación de
>   [Oniguruma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma) (el motor de RegExp) sobre este comportamiento. Todos
>   los otros motores de expresiones regulares, luego de coincidir con una
>   cadena vacía muestran uno de estos dos comportamientos:
>
> - Intentar la próxima coincidencia desde la misma posición, sin permitir una coincidencia de largo cero si no avanza el cursor.
>     [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)[pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre)[php](/questions/tagged/php)[r](/questions/tagged/r)[apache](/questions/tagged/apache)[safari](/questions/tagged/safari)
>     ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/j8fpRT/1)).
> - Avanzar el cursor una posición antes de intentar la próxima coincidencia.
>     [java](/questions/tagged/java)[.net](/questions/tagged/.net)[python](/questions/tagged/python)[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)[go](/questions/tagged/go)[xregexp](/questions/tagged/xregexp)
>     ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/j8fpRT/2)).
>
> > Una nota de color es que versiones previas de IE incrementaban automáticamente
> >     a `.lastIndex` luego de una coincidencia de largo cero con expresiones
> >     globales. 
> >     En el artículo [*An IE lastIndex Bug with Zero-Length Regex Matches*](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/exec-bugs)
> >     se describe con más detalle, y aunque Steven Levithan lo menciona como "bug",
> >     en mi opinión era en realidad la forma correcta de realizarlo, más en
> >     concordancia con lo que expone [Jan Goyvaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33358/jan-goyvaerts) en
> >     [*Watch Out for Zero-Length Matches*](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/).
> >
> > Sin embargo, IE terminó dejando a `.lastIndex` sin incrementar para mostrar
> >     el mismo comportamiento que la mayoría de los navegadores desde IE9
> >     (sólo si se especifica un [DOCTYPE](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) de HTML 4.01 o HTML5) o en IE10+
> >     (sin importar el DOCTYPE).
>
> JavaScript tiene un error de concepción en no utilizar una de
>   estas dos estrategias, rompe la norma del resto de los dialectos
>   (*flavors*) de regex, y en ese sentido es un bug.
>
> El problema radica originalmente en el estándar. En [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) se
>   define a [regexp.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) como "*el índice en el String en donde
>   iniciar el próximo intento de coincidencia*" (en [21.2.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lastindex)) (no
>   dejen que el nombre los engañe, *no es el final de la coincidencia*),
>   y luego:
>
> - Para [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (en [21.2.5.2.2.15.a](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-regexpbuiltinexec))
>
>   > Si es [*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) o [*sticky*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky), asignar a **`"lastIndex"`** el valor de `e` (la posición del final de la coincidencia).
> - Pero para [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) (en [21.2.5.6.6.e.iii.4.c](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-regexp.prototype-@@match))
>
>   > Si es [*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) y la coincidencia es una cadena vacía, asignar a **`"lastIndex"`** el valor de `nextIndex` (la próxima posición en el
>   >     string).
>
> La diferencia entre ambos métodos es inconsistente. Incluso, se
>   reafirma en las notas de compatibilidad hacia atrás, pero sólo para
>   [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) y [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace):
>
> > El comportamiento correcto es que **lastIndex** debe ser incrementado en 1, sólo si el patrón coincidió con una cadena vacía.
> >     (en [D](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-corrections-and-clarifications-in-ecmascript-2015-with-possible-compatibility-impact)).
>
> Y, si bien, sólo sucede con [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), este método
>   es el único que aporta la información completa de una coincidencia.
>   Por ejemplo, es la única forma de obtener el texto capturado por
>   grupos en una expresión global.
>
> En el estándar queda claro que la falta de una definición consistente
>   con el uso de expresiones regulares en cualquier otro lenguaje hace
>   que sea necesario agregar está condición extra para incrementar el
>   índice manualmente, algo totalmente ilógico e innecesario. Este IF
>   es una buena práctica recomendada siempre que se haga un bucle de este
>   estilo.

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque me gustaria saber mas sobre eso de _una condición extra para evitar loops infinitos que se deben a un bug conocido de JavaScript_ ... ..

Comment: @EmanuelVe Si quito los paréntesis me da error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?=(\d{2}6)/: Nothing to repeat`.

Comment: @ArtEze Una aserción positiva (*positive lookahead*) tiene esa estructura `(?=`...`)`. Los paréntesis, el `?` y el `=`, todos forman parte de la construcción, y tienen un significado diferente si se toman por separado. Por lo que no se puede quitar un caracter sin que se modifique rotundamente el comportamiento. Por ejemplo `/a(?=b)/` significa *una "a" seguida de "b", sin incluir a la "b" dentro del texto de la coincidencia*.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Agregué más información sobre el comportamiento de `.lastIndex` y el por qué de ese IF.

Answer (score 4):

Para completar la respuesta de @Mariano, voy a intentar arrojar un poco más de luz en el asunto para que quede totalmente explicado el tema de las `aserciones positivas`.

Como bien explicó @Mariano, usando la siguiente expresión regular `/[0-9]{2}6/g`, estas serían las operaciones que realiza el método `match` sobre el `String` que situaste de ejemplo:

> Con el carácter **|** indicaré el inicio del `match` y con el carácter **^** indicaré los caracteres consumidos y desde dónde se realizaría la próxima búsqueda.

```
1 - |246126667 // hace match de 246
        ^
2 - 246|126667 // hace match de 126
           ^
```

Entonces, para que no ocurra esto puedes hacer dos cosas:

**1 -** Usar el método `exec` y manipular el `lastIndex` de la expresión regular, restándole `2` para que empiece la siguiente búsqueda a partir del siguiente carácter después del inicio del `match`:

```js
var texto = "246126667",
    regex = /[0-9]{2}6/g,
    match,
    matches = [];

while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match[0]);
    regex.lastIndex -= 2;
}

console.log(matches);
```

**2 -** O hacer lo que te recomendó @Mariano: una `aserción positiva`.

Pero con su expresión regular tendrías que manipular también la propiedad `lastIndex` ya que, una aserción positiva no es que haga `match` y regrese al inicio del `match` sino que nunca se mueve de ese sitio (no consume caracteres, porque la misma no forma parte del `match`). No se trata de un bug de `JavaScript` sino que le estamos indicando explícitamente al `script` que no consuma ningún carácter. Tomando de ejemplo la expresión regular `/(?=(\d{2}6))/g`, notemos que la misma no intenta hacer `match` con ningún carácter, pero lo que sí hace es que captura un grupo formado por dos dígitos seguidos de un `6` por lo que podríamos acceder a esta captura con el método `exec`. Veamos cuáles serían los pasos que seguiría el método `exec` en esta expresión regular:

```
1 - |246126667 // hace match al inicio de la cadena, captura el grupo 246 pero no consume caracteres
    ^
2 - |246126667 // hace match al inicio de la cadena, captura el grupo 246 pero no consume caracteres
    ^
3 - |246126667 // hace match al inicio de la cadena, captura el grupo 246 pero no consume caracteres
    ^
.
.
.

N - Loop infinito
```

Por lo tanto si usamos el método `exec` con un `while` la pila de llamadas se llenaría con un `loop` infinito, para evitar esto deberíamos sumar uno a la propiedad `lastIndex` de la expresión regular para que el próximo `match` lo busque a partir de ese sitio:

```js
var texto = "246126667",
    regex = /(?=(\d{2}6))/g,
    match,
    matches = [];

while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
    regex.lastIndex++;
}

console.log(matches);
```

No hace falta hacer la condición `match.index === regex.lastIndex` porque a no ser que la variemos, la propiedad `lastIndex` de la expresión regular se mantendrá invariablemente igual al inicio del `match` debido a que no se consume ningún carácter en dicha expresión.

> **NOTA:** Después de los comentarios mantenidos con @Mariano, he comprobado y ciertamente en `IExplorer 9` e inferiores sería necesaria esta condición ya que estos navegadores pueden incrementar el valor de `lastIndex` si se devuelve un `match` vacío). Si se quisiera crear un código que funcionase en todos los navegadores, se debería seguir el consejo de @Mariano y situar esta condición en el código.

Un método que podrías seguir para no tener que actualizar la propiedad `lastIndex` es utilizar una expresión regular que sí consuma caracteres, por ejemplo esta expresión `/(?=(\d{2}6))\d/g`. Nota que la única cosa que tiene de diferente a la que ha situado @Mariano es que sí hace `match` de un dígito por lo que esta expresión irá consumiendo caracteres. Sigamos los pasos que seguiría el método `exec` con esta expresión regular:

```
1 - |246126667 // hace match de 2, captura el grupo 246
      ^
2 - 246|126667 // hace match de 1, captura el grupo 126
         ^
3 - 2461|26667 // hace match de 2, captura el grupo 266
          ^
4 - 24612|6667 // hace match de 6, captura el grupo 666
           ^
```

```js
var texto = "246126667",
    regex = /(?=(\d{2}6))\d/g,
    match,
    matches = [];

while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: "*Una aserción positiva no es que haga match y regrese al inicio del match sino que nunca se mueve de ese sitio (no consume caracteres, porque la misma no forma parte del match)*" <-- Son dos formas de describir el mismo comportamiento. No obstante, internamente el cursor avanza dentro del lookahead, y vuelve a la posición inicial al salir del mismo.

Comment: "*No se trata de un bug de JavaScript sino que le estamos indicando explícitamente al script que no consuma ningún carácter.*" <-- Creo que no interpretaste bien a lo que llamé "bug". No tiene que ver con que devuelva una cadena vacía, sino al hecho de que ECMA-262 no avance la posición de lastIndex. Edité mi respueta para agregar más información sobre este punto.

Comment: "*No hace falta hacer la condición `match.index === regex.lastIndex` porque a no ser que la variemos, la propiedad `lastIndex` de la expresión regular se mantendrá invariablemente igual al inicio del match*" <-- Esto es incorrecto. En versiones previas de IE, `lastIndex` se incrementa automáticamente luego de coincidir con una cadena vacía. El código **2** devuelve `["246","126","666"]` en esas versiones ([captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9RvL.png)).

Comment: Dicho esto, si bien el código de la respuesta puede ser contraintuitivo, aclaro que voté +1 porque creo que en general aporta información valiosa

Comment: Hola @Mariano, no sé si te he ofendido en algo, no fue mi intención hacerlo. Mi respuesta intenta complementar a la tuya y aportar más información. Creo que no la has tomado en el buen sentido que intenté hacerla. También voté +1 en tu respuesta porque no la considero para nada contraintuitiva (como consideras la mía). No he tenido ni tengo en cuenta `IExplorer 6` hace mucho tiempo y no sé si esto sea un error por mi parte. Creo que debatir lo podemos hacer en un chat y siempre estoy abierto a compartir opiniones y puntos de vista. No considero bueno usar los comentarios para esto.

Comment: En absoluto @ElChiniNet. Me parece un muy buen aporte, y me alegré de ver que se agregue más información en este tema. Mis comentarios estaban dirigidos exclusivamente a puntos específicos de tu respuesta que mencionaban algo de lo que publiqué y que me pareció pertinente aclarar (pero por eso puse el último comentario para remarcar que me parecía buena respuesta). Con contraintuitivo me refiero a que `/(?=(\d{2}6))\d/g` no es lo lógico desde el punto de vista de un regex puro. El índice también se incrementa en IE9- ([captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMyM7.png)), el 6.5% de usuarios.

Comment: Ah, soy yo el que ha malinterpretado entonces tus comentarios, discúlpame por ello ;)
No obtengo los mismos resultados en IE9 (en IE8 sí) (y no sé cómo situar capturas en los comentarios)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54840/discussion-between-elchininet-and-mariano).

Comment: Como resumen del chat, IE dejó de incrementar `.lastIndex` desde IE9 (sólo si se especifica un DOCTYPE de HTML 4.01 o HTML 5) y en IE10+ (sin importar el DOCTYPE).