# ¿Por qué hay que evitar un loop infinito con expresiones regulares incrementando RegExp.lastIndex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta es la forma recomendada de obtener todas las coincidencias y capturas de una expresión regular en JavaScript, en donde el resultado puede ser una cadena vacía:

```js
const texto = "ab-cde",
      regex = /(?=(\w{2}))/g;
let   match;

while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) { //evitar loop infinito
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log('Texto: "' + match[0] + '"', '\tPosición:', match.index);
    console.log(' -Grupo 1: "' + match[1] + '"');
}
```

1. ¿Por qué hay que incrementar [`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) para evitar un loop infinito?
2. ¿Cuando hay que usarlo? ¿Sólo ocurre con [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/exec) usando el modificador [`/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)?
3. ¿Es exclusivo de JavaScript o también ocurre con otros dialectos de regex?
4. ¿Se comporta de esta manera en todos los navegadores?
5. ¿Es un bug o está especificado así por diseño?

Comment: Originalmente lo había agregado como una nota, a pedido, en mi respuesta a [*Obtener todas las coincidencias solapadas en expresiones regulares*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53129/127). Sin embargo, creo que tiene más utilidad viviendo como una pregunta independiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¿Por qué es necesario evitar un loop infinito?**

La condición es para ver si el inicio de la coincidencia (`match.index`) es la misma posición que donde se iniciará el siguiente intento (`regex.lastIndex`). En caso de que sea la misma, se incrementa en 1 la posición.

```
if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) { //evitar loop infinito
    regex.lastIndex++;
}
```

Esto se debe a que, como la coincidencia es en realidad [de largo cero](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html), ya que la [inspección](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) no consume caracteres, y el resultado del método realmente es una cadena vacía (`""`), la posición desde donde se intenta el regex no avanza ninguna posición. Por eso, se modifica manualmente para que no siga intentando coincidir desde la misma posición, entrando en un loop infinito.

> Si coincidió desde una posición, obviamente va a seguir coincidiendo desde esa misma posición de nuevo, y de nuevo, y de nuevo...

**¿Cuándo hay que usarlo?**

Esta condición es una buena práctica a utilizar en todos los casos en los que se utilice el modificador [`/g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) ([global](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)) y un bucle con [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). Obviamente no sucede con [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test) ni con [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match), donde no hay un control iterativo sobre cada uno de los intentos de coincidencia.

Además, no todos los navegadores se comportan igual. Incluso en expresiones que no deberían jamás devolver una cadena vacía, es una buena salvaguarda, y recomiendo **utilizar siempre esta construcción**.

**¿Sólo en JavaScript? ¿En todos los navegadores?**

JavaScript tiene una de las peores implementaciones de expresiones regulares dentro de los lenguajes comúnmente utilizados ([ver más info](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-javascript.html#crippled)). Todos los otros motores de expresiones regulares, luego de coincidir con una cadena vacía muestran uno de estos dos comportamientos:

- Intentar la próxima coincidencia desde la misma posición, sin permitir una coincidencia de largo cero si no avanza el cursor. [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)[pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre)[php](/questions/tagged/php)[r](/questions/tagged/r)[apache](/questions/tagged/apache)[safari](/questions/tagged/safari) ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/j8fpRT/1)).
- Avanzar el cursor una posición antes de intentar la próxima coincidencia. [java](/questions/tagged/java)[.net](/questions/tagged/.net)[python](/questions/tagged/python)[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)[go](/questions/tagged/go)[xregexp](/questions/tagged/xregexp) ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/j8fpRT/2)).

> Una nota de color es que versiones previas de IE incrementaban automáticamente
>   a `.lastIndex` luego de una coincidencia de largo cero con expresiones
>   globales. 
>   En el artículo [*An IE lastIndex Bug with Zero-Length Regex Matches*](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/exec-bugs)
>   se describe con más detalle, y aunque Steven Levithan lo menciona como "bug",
>   en mi opinión era en realidad la forma correcta de realizarlo, más en
>   concordancia con lo que expone [Jan Goyvaerts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33358/jan-goyvaerts) en
>   [*Watch Out for Zero-Length Matches*](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/).
>
> Sin embargo, IE terminó dejando a `.lastIndex` sin incrementar para mostrar
>   el mismo comportamiento que la mayoría de los navegadores desde IE9
>   (sólo si se especifica un [DOCTYPE](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) de HTML 4.01 o HTML5) o en IE10+
>   (sin importar el DOCTYPE).

JavaScript tiene un error de concepción en no utilizar una de estas dos estrategias, rompe la norma del resto de los dialectos (*flavors*) de regex, y en ese sentido es un bug.

**¿Bug o por diseño?**

Si bien este comportamiento no es un "*bug*" *per se* ([*<sub><sup>RESOLVED INVALID</sup></sub>*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=252356) en Bugzilla), utilicé el término porque es un concepto erróneo en la implementación de [Oniguruma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma) (el motor de RegExp) sobre este comportamiento.

El problema radica originalmente en el estándar. En [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) se define a [regexp.lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) como "*el índice en el String en donde iniciar el próximo intento de coincidencia*" (en [21.2.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lastindex)) (no dejen que el nombre los engañe, *no es el final de la coincidencia*), y luego:

- Para [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (en [21.2.5.2.2.15.a](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-regexpbuiltinexec))

  > Si es [*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) o [*sticky*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky), asignar a **`"lastIndex"`** el valor de `e` (la posición del final de la coincidencia).
- Pero para [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) (en [21.2.5.6.6.e.iii.4.c](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-regexp.prototype-@@match))

  > Si es [*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) y la coincidencia es una cadena vacía, asignar a **`"lastIndex"`** el valor de `nextIndex` (la próxima posición en el string).

La diferencia entre ambos métodos es inconsistente. Incluso, se reafirma en las notas de compatibilidad hacia atrás, pero sólo para [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) y [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace):

> El comportamiento correcto es que **lastIndex** debe ser incrementado en 1, sólo si el patrón coincidió con una cadena vacía. (en [D](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-corrections-and-clarifications-in-ecmascript-2015-with-possible-compatibility-impact)).

Y, si bien, sólo sucede con [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), este método es el único que aporta la información completa de una coincidencia (es el principal con regex). Por ejemplo, es la única forma de obtener el texto capturado por grupos en una expresión global.

**Conclusiones**

En el estándar queda claro que la falta de una definición consistente con el uso de expresiones regulares en cualquier otro lenguaje hace que sea necesario agregar está condición extra para incrementar el índice manualmente, algo totalmente ilógico e innecesario. Este IF es una buena práctica recomendada siempre que se haga un bucle de este estilo.